# Isn't the html of the form Django displays on the screen?

Tags: html, django

Django shows you forms when you do basic coding, right?
Where is the html of the automatically generated form in windows?

So instead of looking for a template folder, once the developer writes the url or views code, he finds the location of the skeleton-only html that Django shows.

In my opinion, it looks like it's built somewhere like an "anaconda/envs" contains a separate virtual environment, but I can't find it.

it's maybe path?

Answer (score 0):

It's well documented:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/renderers/

> It loads templates first from the built-in form templates directory in
>   django/forms/templates

unless you have 3rd party libraries included that override these templates.

However, a quick check in https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/ shows that this directory is empty.

tl;dr

Django does not render any forms from scratch (unless it's the Admin which of course creates its whole UI automatically). It just enables you to quickly create a template that can render your form but you will still have to provide a basic template (aka HTML markup with dynamic parts) yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much.
A while ago, I found out that such things exist in Python because of my administrator. Eventually I understood that I had to separate the html code from the Python program and write it to the template folder.

In fact, I don't want to do it. ^^